# PowerShell - Expressions are only allowed as the first element in a pipeline

Tags: powershell, cmd, scripting

So, i'm trying to do the following using CMD:

```
start powershell.exe -NoExit -command "$host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'White' | $host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = 'Black'"
```

This of course returns the error that expressions can only be the first element of a pipeline, now how would i still get these 2 things? I'm new to PowerShell and i know a bit of it but i'm not an expert in pipelines.

Comment: `$host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'White';$host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = 'Black'` try that instead.

Comment: You want two commands then, not a pipeline. Just use `;` to separate them.

Comment: If you want those lines to run when you start a new PowerShell, you can put them [in a profile script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1).